# Make iOS Simulator smaller than 25% size?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Hey is there a way to make the iPhone 7 Plus Simulator smaller than what I can reach with CMD+5? The "smallest" option blocks more than half of my screen (see picture). I need it for development with Apple Watch.

[image]

Comment: Why does it matter? Surely you Command+Tab away from it when you're not using it?

Comment: I always have it in front because I mostly do logic stuff so a tiny iPhone is sufficient to get an idea of what's running and what isn't

Comment: Well, do you need to test it on 7+? If you run it on 5/5S/SE it would be smaller by design :) also, if the picture is in fact your whole screen, I'd suggest a new, bigger monitor.

Comment: I haven't found a way to use the Watch Simulator with another device than the 7 yet. It's my MacBook monitor, you'd expect Apple to take care of the products they sell

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a iphone 5s or 5 on the simulator. At 25% it is pretty small.

Here is a picture of my desktop
[image]